# retrieve access records that fall between user specified dates

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

The table has a date field that is text. The SQL statement is:

```
"SELECT datefield, anotherfield FROM tablename WHERE CDate(datefield) BETWEEN #" & dateStart & "# AND #" & dateEnd & "#"
```

`dateStart` and `dateEnd` are strings, like "10/02/2017" and "10/4/2017". I used `CDate` to convert the string `datefield` to a date, and the bracketing # around the start and end date strings so that they will be treated as date. I have tried, literally, dozens of different variants of the WHERE clause with no luck. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: `The table has a date field that is text` Dates are **not** text, they are dates.  If you want them to act like dates store them as dates and use dates to poll the DB. The problem is that `"10/02/2017"` will always look less than `"9/1/1935"` because `"1"` **is** less than `"9"`.    Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

I certainly agree that dates should not be stored as text. However, if you are stuck with the table design then you will need to use CDate for all three of your "date" fields:

```
SELECT CDate([datefield]) AS myDate, anotherfield
FROM Table2
WHERE (((CDate([datefield])) Between CDate([dateStart]) And CDate([dateEnd])));
```

Answer (score -1):

I've also used your ways in storing and retrieving date in mySQL. However, I only used one field instead of your perspective `dateStart` and `dateEnd`. I would suggest you only create one field for storing date. Here's how I managed to catch the values between those dates using VB.NET.

```
SELECT datefield, anotherfield FROM tablename WHERE datestoredfield BETWEEN '" & selectedDateFrom.toString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "' AND '" & selectedDateTo.toString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "';
```

I've indicated `.toString("MM/dd/yyyy")` at the end of the selected dates its because your current stored date format in your date field is `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: This will never work except if using the `yyyy-mm-dd` format. Still, see comment from @Plutonix